# NextcloudPi Ethernet DHCP failure diagnostics sought

Tags: nextcloud, nextcloudpi

Context:

- Home networked rPi3: NCP (NextCloudPi)
- Network tests return expected results & functionality
- rPi3 ethernet hardware test validate hardware

Observations & symptoms:

- was working perfectly until recently.
- Fails to retrieve ethernet LAN IP through DHCP
- **Ethernet Hardware = good:** DHCP tested via OSMC micro SD card

  - Green Ethernet LED does not blink, Yellow blinks
  - OSMC test returns expected LAN IP address: 192.X.X.114 and responds to ping requests

**What questions must be asked to determine command line diagnostics?**  I would like to understand the root cause of the problem(s)

Photo shows eth0 is not assigned LAN IP address:

[image]

Comment: I see that when you used OSMC the Ethernet works, but I'd look at physical things first.. Are there 'link' lights on your Ethernet port? Can you swap out the Ethernet cable(s)? What else changed? (or) what were you doing when it stopped? What else do you know about the network, can you talk to the net Administrator? One other thing though, can you test whether WiFi works, although having both interfaces up may be a problem. Dave

Comment: @DaveW Thank you for responding.  Workaround: enabled wifi via `su; sudo ncp-config`.  OSMC tests indicate ethernet hardware is good.  The ethernet software must be hosed?  OP updated to address questions.